# tomcat startup error post ssl certificate setup

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, tomcat8, pfx

I am getting the below error when starting the server

```
30-Jan-2018 07:04:54.821 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
**30-Jan-2018 07:04:55.157 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
 java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.**
        at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getLength(DerInputStream.java:561)
        at sun.security.util.DerValue.init(DerValue.java:365)
        at sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:320)
        at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1914)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getStore(JSSESocketFactory.java:424)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeystore(JSSESocketFactory.java:323)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:581)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:521)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:357)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:732)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:457)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:576)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:599)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)

**30-Jan-2018 07:04:55.159 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]**
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
```

Any idea anyone. I have defined the connectors in server.xml but I am not so sure about the ssl certificate. I had a .pfx certificate with me. I then created a keystore, imported the certificate and then configured the connectors.then I used this keystore in server.xml

Comment: Maybe you need the unlimited security JARs in your JRE: https://support.ca.com/us/knowledge-base-articles.tec1698523.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with pfx file, there is no need to create a key store as you can directly use pfx file and password inside your connector

```
 <Connector server="Application Server" port="8443" protocol="$PROTOCOL"
           maxThreads="100" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           keystoreFile="${PFX_FILE}" keystorePass="${PFX_PWD}"
           keystoreType="PKCS12" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" connectionTimeout="80000"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I then created a keystore, imported the certificate, and then configured the connectors

Not sufficient. You also needed to import the private key. Or use the PFX as a keystore directly.